# MySQL Error 1042 when trying to connect from Excel AddIn

Tags: c#, mysql, excel, add-in

I am trying to connect to local mysql database from within excel AddIn.

Problem is that exactly the same code works in standalone windows c# app but when used in AddIn for Office (in my case Excel) - I'm getting MySQL error no 1042 (Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts). I do not know how to debug it. The library I am using is MySQL  Connector/Net http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net . It register libraries that I can later add as a reference in Visual Studio. Both the app and the AddIn are .NET 4.5 projects but I'm not sure it's the library issue as it loads properly (it gets back the error).

Anyway the error looks meaningless to me because it doesn't say **why** it couldn't connect. Someone in other question at SO suggested that 1042 means that it couldn't resolve the hostname but I am using an IP address.

This is the code

```
if (connection == null)
{
    connection = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=127.0.0.1;DATABASE=mydb;UID=root;PASSWORD=;");
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        return "Cannot connect to SQL [" + e.Number + "](" + e.Message + ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: The MySQL server is running on the same machine on which the Excel is running?

Comment: Yes and as I said, exactly *the same* code works when ran in an standalone c# app (winforms).